# Is it possible to reference an existing ActiveRecord model from the classes generated with Gii?

Tags: yii2, yii2-giiant

There is an extension for Yii2 I'm using, and it provides a database table and an `ActiveRecord` model class to work with entities in that table. My other models are generated with Giiant. I want to reference the library model from my generated models, e.g. so relation properties like `$myEntity->thatLibraryEntity` are generated correctly by Giiant. Is it possible to do so?

I haven't found a way to do so in the documentation, and in the source code the closest thing to what I want is setting the `BatchController::$tableNameMap` configuration parameter in Giiant, but that seems to only rename the models, and I would like to tell Giiant which existing `ActiveRecord` to use for entities in a particular table.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it.

The generated models reference class `app\models\ThatLibraryEntity` for table `that_library_entity`. I created that class, and made it extend the library ActiveRecord model I wanted to use.